# Finding a Eulerian circuit on an NxM rectangular grid

Tags: graph

The graph for the 8 x 9 grid depicted in the photo is Eulerian and solved with a braiding algorithm which for an N x M grid only works if N and M are relatively prime.  A general algorithm like Hierholzer could be used but its regularity implies the existence of a deterministic algorithm to traverse the (2N+1) x (2M +1) verticies of the graph.  I'm stuggling to find this algorithm but I'm sure it's there.

The motivation for this question is that continous extrusion with a 3D printer relies on Eulerian circuits to traverse all edges of the graph once and once only which is desirable for creating strong structures in plastic, clay or cement.

[image: 8 x 9 grid printed as a continuous extrusion]

Comment: This site is focused on programming-related questions. I think that [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) are better places to seek help with algorithms.

Comment: There is a rather boring solution which traverses the bottom edge, the left edge and then zigzags back and forth to complete the circuit. However this solution maximizes the number of turns in the path when for strength (and printing speed), I want to minimise the turns.  This requires an algorithm which uses vertex weights of a rather special kind, rather than edge weights.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I arrived at was to modify the Hierholzer algorithm slightly.  Rather than choose the next adjacent vertex at random, if possible choose the vertex which lies on the same diagonal direction.  This means weighting each edge with a code for the diagonal direction it is on and maintaining the direction as the algorithm proceeds.  The adjacency structure is an array of lists of weighted edges.